# The created hook does not work at all or not correctly

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

My index.js/

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import Users from './components/Users.vue';
import Home from './components/Home.vue';
import About from './components/About.vue';
import Contacts from './components/Contacts.vue';
import CategoryItemList from './components/CategoryItemList.vue';
import './static/css/main.css';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
Vue.use(VueRouter);
const routes = [
   {path: '/users/:teamId', name: 'users', component: Users},
   {path: '/', name: 'home', component: Home, children: [
     {path: 'cat/:id', name: 'category-item-list', component: 
      CategoryItemList }]}];

const router = new VueRouter({mode: 'hash', routes});

export default new Vue({ el: '#root', router, render: h => h(App) });
```

My component with list of categories and router-links/

```
<template lang="pug">
 div
  nav
   <li v-for="category in categories" v-bind:category="category">
    <router-link :to="{name: 'category-item-list', params: {id: category.id} 
                      }">{{category.title}}</router-link>
  </li>
</template>

<script>
   export default {
     name: "category-navigation",
  data: function () {
    return {
      categories: [
        {'title': 'first', 'id': 1},
        {'title': 'second', 'id': 2},
        {'title': 'third', 'id': 3}
      ]
    }
  }
 }
 </script>
```

My component for category//

```
<template>
<div class="category" v-if="category">
  <h1>{{category.title}}</h1>
  <p>{{category.id}}</p>
  <span>{{this.$route.params.id}}</span>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "category-item-list",
    data: function () {
      return {
        categories: [
          {'title': 'first', 'id': 1},
          {'title': 'second', 'id': 2},
          {'title': 'third', 'id': 3}
        ],
        category: null
      }
    },
    created: function () {
      let catId = this.$route.params.id - 1;
      console.log(catId);
      console.log(this.$route.params.id);
      this.category = this.categories[catId]
    }
}
</script>
```

Routes worked correctly, and i get {{this.$route.params.id}} 
meaning different each time, but not change category. those. the variable catId once got the value and does not change. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has to do with your routes, specifically the children:

```
const routes = [
{
    path: '/users/:teamId', 
    name: 'users',
    component: Users
},
{
    path: '/', 
    name: 'home',
    component: Home,
    children: [
    {
        path: 'cat/:id',
        name: 'category-item-list', 
        component: CategoryItemList
    }]
}
];
```

Having `cat/:id` nested under your `/` route is incorrect, as well as the larger problem which is you are not providing a `<router-view></router-view>` outlet for the nested components. From the docs:

```
a rendered component can also contain its own, nested <router-view>. 
....
To render components into this nested outlet, we need to use the children option in VueRouter constructor config
```

Have a close look at the working example if you have not already, this will better help you understand:

https://jsfiddle.net/yyx990803/L7hscd8h/

See: https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/nested-routes.html

Notice the examples nest routes when the page is related to a specific resource, i.e. `/cat/:id` at the top level and then, for example, `/edit` as a child, so `/cat/:id/edit` would be the result.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I'm just starting to learn Vue, and I'm probably doing something with components. I just want to navigate the list within the Home tab, but at the moment either it does not work, or when it clicks it goes to the category but leaves Home and, accordingly, lost navigation.

Comment: Updated answer, hoping it helps clarify.

Comment: Thank you so much. You pointed out to me the direction, I think I can figure out that for a couple of days these things do not work, and I took it to write the front for my api for jango rest, my first front framework!

Comment: Excellent, I think once you have the fundamentals of Vue well understood, it'll quickly become one of your favorites. Glad I could!

Comment: By the way, I still did it my own way) and everything works great. The only problem was that I created this in $ hook.params.id and passed it as an index of the array element to get the element, but did not update it, the problem was solved using the updated hook, I just had to update the variable. But you still thank you very much)

Answer (score 0):

Answer this task:
Using hook updated for refresh variable catId:

```
created: function () {
      let catId = this.$route.params.id - 1;
      this.category = this.categories[catId]
    },
    updated: function () {
      let catId = this.$route.params.id - 1;
      this.category = this.categories[catId]
    }enter code here
```

Comment: Makes sense. Also note you can set up a watcher on `$route`. https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/dynamic-matching.html

Comment: I'm sorry, but have little question:) Why is it so far in my template while <span> {{this. $ Route.params.id}} </ span> works, and without it, no, magic...?